# How to disable button using jquery onReady

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I am using flexigrid and jquery in my project. I have grid and on top of grid, I have buttons. When page will be loaded I want to disable these buttons and depending on my conditions I want to enable either of the buttons.

```
buttons: [
    { name: 'Batch Browse', bclass: 'browse', onpress: showBatchBrowse },
```

Can you please help me to get this done using flexigrid and JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

add 'disabled' string at the end of button names that you want be disable.
and rename them to orginal when you want be active again.

Comment: it doesn't work after adding the 'disabled' string at the end.
can you give me an example?